# User editing cell in TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-xe3, editbox, stringgrid

How do you allow a user to edit text in a TStringGrid cell.

Comment: Check the properties of your stringgrid. You can set checkboxes to determine if the user is allowed to edit cells and or columns.

Answer (score 10):

Enable the `goEditing` flag, and optionally the `goAlwaysShowEditor` flag, in the `TStringGrid.Options` property.